# Conditional update/insert document in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to avoid as many round trips as possible and need to do the following operation in mongoDB:

```
if(documentDoesnotExist(id)) {
    // Insert new document
}
else if(doc.id == id && doc.otherField != otherField) {
    // Clear an array in this document and add 'otherField' to it
}
else if(doc.id == id && doc.otherField == otherField) {
    // Add otherField to an array in this document
}
```

I can't seem to find a way with findAndModify(upset:true) or update(upset:true) that will allow me to do this in one db call. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yep, I don't think it's possible in one call. If mongo had stored procedures, that's where you'd use them.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @SergioTulentsev. Any idea on what would the most performant way to do this? I was thinking I could do a remove for the first else if case and then after do a findAndModify with upset set to true.

Comment: Possibly. Hard to tell, your example is a bit too abstract. In any case, two queries is better than three.